# Acceptance tests done first...how can this be accomplished?

Tags: agile, testing, development-process, tdd

The basic gist of most Agile methods is that a feature is not "done" until it's been developed, tested, and in many cases released.  This is supposed to happen in quick turnaround chunks of time such as "Sprints" in the Scrum process.

A common part of Agile is also TDD, which states that tests are done first.

My team works on a GUI program that does a lot of specific drawing and such.  In order to provide tests, the testing team needs to be able to work with something that at least attempts to perform the things they are trying to test.  We've found no way around this problem.

I can very much see where they are coming from because if I was trying to write software that targeted some basically mysterious interface I'd have a very hard time.  Although we have behavior fairly well specified, the exact process of interacting with various UI elements when it comes to automation seems to be too unique to a feature to allow testers to write automated scripts to drive something that does not exist.  Even if we could, a lot of things end up turning up later as having been missing from the specification.

One thing we considered doing was having the testers write test "scripts" that are more like a set of steps that must be performed, as described from a use-case perspective, so that they can be "automated" by a human being.  This can then be performed by the developer(s) writing the feature and/or verified by someone else.  When the testers later get an opportunity they automate the "script" for regression purposes mainly.  This didn't end up catching on in the team though.

The testing part of the team is actually falling behind us by quite a margin.  This is one reason why the apparently extra time of developing a "script" for a human being to perform just did not happen....they're under a crunch to keep up with us developers.  If we waited for them, we'd get nothing done.  It's not their fault really, they're a bottle neck but they're doing what they should be and working as fast as possible.  The process itself seems to be set up against them.

Very often we end up having to go back a month or more in what we've done to fix bugs that the testers have finally gotten to checking.  It's an ugly truth that I'd like to do something about.

So what do other teams do to solve this fail cascade?  How can we get testers ahead of us and how can we make it so that there's actually time for them to write tests for the features we do in a sprint without making us sit and twiddle our thumbs in the meantime?  As it's currently going, in order to get a feature "done", using agile definitions, would be to have developers work for 1 week, then testers work the second week, and developers hopefully being able to fix all the bugs they come up with in the last couple days.  That's just not going to happen, even if I agreed it was a reasonable solution.  I need better ideas...

Answer (score 7):

first, get rid of the split between 'testers' and 'developers'. *Everyone tests*

second, in TDD, the developers code the tests *before* they code the feature/story

What you have described is not TDD [it may be Scrum though; Scrum is a project-management methodology independent of the development methodology; Scrum is not relevant to your problem]

Scenarios where automated testing is impossible are *exceedingly* rare. Scenarios where automated testing is difficult, expensive, or inconvenient are much more common - but it is precisely these scenarios where automated testing is needed the most.

From the vague description, I assume the software is drawing something on the screen. If what is being drawn is determined by data, formulas, or functional steps, then at least write automated tests that test to the level of the data/formulas/functional steps. If the screen output is deterministic (the same steps result in the same drawing output every time) then test manually once, take a screenshot, and let future tests compare the output to the verified screenshot. If the screen output is nondeterministic and not governed by data, formulas, or functional steps, then you're in that rare area where automated testing may be impossible. But I doubt it.

I'm guessing that the only reason testing has not been automated so far is that **the developers don't care about it**. In TDD, the developers do the testing, so they feel the pain of the boring repetition of testing the same 62-step process a hundred times until all the bugs are gone. Nothing will get an automated testing solution developed faster than making the developers do the testing.

Comment: I'm speaking specifically of acceptance tests, not unit tests.  At any rate, I'm not going to have the opportunity to alter the departmental structure of the company.  Need a solution that works with both developers and "developers in test".  That said, how would you do your screenshot example before there was something to screenshot?  There's actually a LOT of our automated tests that do this, but before anything like that can be automated there has to be something to take a screenshot of.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: TDD defines tests for user stories which define the features of the application. The terminology of 'unit test' is often used in this context, but it does not have the same limited meaning that it would in a purely unit-testing methodology (where code coverage would matter, for example). TDD tests **features**, and scales up to the acceptance-testing level. The use of the term 'unit testing' in the literature is a regrettable point of confusion for many people. As for the screenshot, you have to run the thing successfully once so that approach is only good for regression testing.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: with a name like Crazy Eddie, I would expect you to be the champion of challenging pointless inefficient cycles of failure ;-) [yes i read your blog]. Seriously though, nothing is going to change because the developers feel no pain. Let them feel the pain - or maybe offer them some kind of reward for helping - and they will come up with a solution for automated testing, and/or starting writing code that is easier to test.

Comment: The difference that I see as being most important from my perspective is that they require different areas of expertise.  A unit test can, and often is, written in the same language as the application bits they test.  Automated acceptance testing on the other hand makes use of whatever language the particular software used to drive the UI responds to.  They require different architectures as well, as at least our testers have developed huge libraries of reusable components they adapt for specific needs.  Just like a team can involve DB experts vs. code, it seems fine to have test experts.

Comment: I guess this solves the issue of keeping developers busy while tests are done though.  Even if it takes them longer for any given task, it could be worthwhile.  I may very well not get the buy in I need though and I imagine the problem to just keep resurfacing until we can figure out how to get the tests written ahead of time or at least in sync.  I still don't see any way to solve this issue as the requirement of having something there to drive seems to be a prerequisite of the automation problem.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: now you are defending the process you were complaining about in the question ;-) I'm not denying that there may be a tool/expertise split that is relevant, but as long as testing is viewed by the developers as "someone else's problem", nothing will change.

Comment: Actually, I just don't think that's an accurate assessment of the team.  We actually spend a lot of time on the application trying to make it as easy for the test developers as possible.  We've had to override the Qt accessibility plugin, and are very often having to go back into something we've already developed because something about the automation process is failing.  I don't think the issue is that we're not working together or sharing pain, but that we can't seem to get the two aspects to happen in the right order or even close to each other.

Comment: Testing does seem to be seen as a second-class citizen though.  When we do our story point evaluations, we've been told to just do development effort.  We show things at the sprint report meetings that haven't even been seen by a test script.  App devs have been pushed to go faster and faster, without even really paying attention to what is even happening in the test portions.  I have no control over these issues though but if there where a way to get the testing part ahead or work out how to get it done at the same time without slowing "development" I might be able to get that to happen.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: I've got to go (before Anna clamps down on us for having a discussion in the comments instead of using the chat rooms, which I can't seem to figure out) but please call me tomorrow if you like (profile >> website >> phone#), no charge.

Comment: Too bad an important conversation has to be cut short over something like that.  Use of chat or phone of course limits the abilities of anyone trying to learn by listening.  An unfortunate reminder why I stopped posting on SE sites and probably shouldn't have started again.  I'm going to discuss your ideas with the rest of the team.  There's other things I'd like to bring up for discussion but if that's just going to get us moderated anyway there's not much point.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: if we come up with a solution we can always come back and post it here. I'm teasing Anna but she's right, the comments are not meant to be for long discussions.

Comment: @Steven For the record, moving lengthy discussions to chat and/or incorporating information into answers is a [general policy](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/how-do-our-moderators-and-community-members-feel-about-cleaning-up-comment-nois/1508#1508), not my personal whim. Discussions in themselves aren't a problem. Just the unconstructive ones or ones that turn up useful information that forever remains hidden deep in comments are. I appreciate you trying to move the discussion, but if you could not frame it as "Anna will get you", that'd be cool. Thanks.

Comment: @Anna: just teasing you; we all love the mods.

Answer (score 5):

My teams found that TDD wasn't adequate for designing GUI tests. All of the automated GUI level testing frameworks we used required code to be written before the test. So we switched to [Behavior Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development). Sure, the tests aren't automated, but it did give us a way to measure if the UI was "done-done" from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

We find ATDD for the GUI to difficult/expensive.

We usually do the front-end first.  Since we write webapps it's usually in HTML/CSS/JS, and then we get sign-off on the the look, flow, etc.  These will eventually get translatedinto templates with the appropriate parts replaced with dynamic bits.

Once the UI mockup is complete we write tests that mimic a web request.  XPath is used to assert the data exists in the correct HTML tags.

We find this style of testing gives us good value for the time we spend.  We still assert the data is returned, and some general structure about the html.  Since we already worked out the look beforehand through the mockup stage we don't worry about trying to assert pixel placement.  We just look at the page as we develop both as part of development as well as a double check.

For GUI non-web dev I would probably try add some hooks to make the front end scriptable.  I would probably also mockup the UI first as well, even if on paper.

Answer (score 2):

> One thing we considered doing was having the testers write test "scripts" that are more like a set of steps that must be performed, as described from a use-case perspective, so that they can be "automated" by a human being. This can then be performed by the developer(s) writing the feature and/or verified by someone else. When the testers later get an opportunity they automate the "script" for regression purposes mainly. This didn't end up catching on in the team though.

This is more or less what we do. Every feature is developed in parallell with the test case (script) and no feature is 'done' until all three steps is done: development, test case and testing. All test cases are written from the requirements by testers and checked with the developers, so we all have a common understanding of the problem. Like your 'every other week' suggestion, except that when the developers are working on the feature the testers are working on test cases and when the testers are testing the developers are investigating the next feature.

I think the biggest problem you have is that

> [t]he testing part of the team is actually falling behind us by quite a margin. [...] If we waited for them, we'd get nothing done

Since the test team is so far behind I really think you ought to wait for them. I'm sure there are something productive you could do - such as develop some features that are easy to test but takes a lot of time to develop. It can also help to take test time into consideration when planing a sprint, neither developers or testers should be overworked or idle.

Answer (score 1):

```
 > Acceptance tests done first…how can this be accomplished?
```

I prefer a bdd-tdd-style of development as described in this article: [Behavior-Driven Development with SpecFlow and WatiN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490346.aspx).

The Example uses .net for development with SpecFlow + NUnit + WaitN. If you are developing with (j)ruby/java you can try cucumber + junit + waitr

Answer (score 1):

Acceptance test-driven development (distinct from, but complementary to test-driven development) is a great way to ensure that you have the requirements nailed before you begin coding.

On my team we (product owner, QA analysts and developers) sit together and use [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) two write acceptance tests. These sessions are usually driven by QA but we all participate. These won't run straight away since some development effort is needed to add the *fixtures* (the glue between the wiki pages and the production code). These tests form the acceptance criteria for a *story*. FitNesse is designed to interact with the layer below the UI.

As developers we then work to make these acceptance tests pass. We use TDD for this, but TDD should not be confused with ATDD.

Once the FitNesse pages turn green we are *almost* done we still have some work to do (exploratory testing, usually lead by QA, and so forth).

Comment: I see how unit tests and acceptance tests shouldn't be confused. Not that Uncle Bob is a god, but in "Agile Principles, Patterns and Practices in C#" he includes acceptance testing (and uses FitNesse) as a part of TDD and doesn't make a distinction and doesn't even mention ATDD.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe writing [coded UI tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681.aspx) can help you out. If you are working with Visual studio 2010 you can use an add-in called "coded ui test" for recording and coding a very specific script for interacting with the UI of your app. Recording an interaction into a script introduces an extra level of abstraction which guards you aganist small changes in the UI. However introducing this form of testing also introduces the burden of maintaining the tests.

Answer (score 0):

8 years later the situation is pretty clear, everyone who tried to do it failed.

Upfront and maybe all kind of testing doesn't work efficient for the topmost interaction GUI layer. It's a bit better for WebUIs because they are much simpler in general but for GUIs when mouse movement and Drag&Drops are involved: don't waste to much time with testing.

Test the lower level of the logic and states you use in GUI. Here some GUI scripting products and processes can help you to get something done. But most time instead of testing use DesignByContract or also known as use tons of assert statements and invariant checks. And leave them in code while beta testing. Make sure you have enough asserts that any error can be found and fixed immediately.

For acceptance tests, just write them down as you write down normal specifications in traditional waterfall systems. Just rewrite them in every cycle.

Agile,TDD and BDD is only a useable development method for a subset of software. Dont try to use it outside the domain where it was intended to be used.